# multi label classification using Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am total noob in tensorflow so trying to implemente this [multi label classification example](https://github.com/BinRoot/TensorFlow-Book/blob/master/ch04_classification/softmax.py) using tensorflow 2.0.

Here is my source code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=320)

# training settings
learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 10000
display_step = 100
num_labels = 3

# input data per label
x1_label0 = np.random.normal(1, 1, (50, 1)).astype(np.float64)
x2_label0 = np.random.normal(1, 1, (50, 1)).astype(np.float64)
x1_label1 = np.random.normal(5, 1, (50, 1)).astype(np.float64)
x2_label1 = np.random.normal(12, 1, (50, 1)).astype(np.float64)
x1_label2 = np.random.normal(10, 1, (50, 1)).astype(np.float64)
x2_label2 = np.random.normal(0, 1, (50, 1)).astype(np.float64)

plt.scatter(x1_label0, x2_label0, c='r', marker='o', s=20)
plt.scatter(x1_label1, x2_label1, c='g', marker='x', s=20)
plt.scatter(x1_label2, x2_label2, c='b', marker='_', s=20)
plt.show()

# input data. both labels together
xs_label0 = np.hstack((x1_label0, x2_label0))
xs_label1 = np.hstack((x1_label1, x2_label1))
xs_label2 = np.hstack((x1_label2, x2_label2))
xs = np.vstack((xs_label0, xs_label1, xs_label2))


labels = np.matrix([[1., 0., 0.]] * len(x1_label0) +
                   [[0., 1., 0.]] * len(x1_label1) +
                   [[0., 0., 1.]] * len(x1_label2))


test_x1_label0 = np.random.normal(1, 1, (10, 1)).astype(np.float64)
test_x2_label0 = np.random.normal(1, 1, (10, 1)).astype(np.float64)
test_x1_label1 = np.random.normal(5, 1, (10, 1)).astype(np.float64)
test_x2_label1 = np.random.normal(12, 1, (10, 1)).astype(np.float64)
test_x1_label2 = np.random.normal(10, 1, (10, 1)).astype(np.float64)
test_x2_label2 = np.random.normal(0, 1, (10, 1)).astype(np.float64)
test_xs_label0 = np.hstack((test_x1_label0, test_x2_label0))
test_xs_label1 = np.hstack((test_x1_label1, test_x2_label1))
test_xs_label2 = np.hstack((test_x1_label2, test_x2_label2))

test_xs = np.vstack((test_xs_label0, test_xs_label1, test_xs_label2))
test_labels = np.matrix([[1., 0., 0.]] * 10 + [[0., 1., 0.]] * 10 + [[0., 0., 1.]] * 10)

train_size, num_features = xs.shape

# weights
w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_features, num_labels], dtype=np.float64), name="w", trainable=True)
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_labels], dtype=np.float64))

# function of output from inputs
def model(x):
    y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, w) + b)
    return y

# losses computation function
def cost(y_pred, y_true):
    return -tf.reduce_sum(y_true * tf.math.log(y_pred))


optimizer = tf.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate)


def run_optimization():
    with tf.GradientTape() as g:
        pred = model(xs)  # calculate output using inputs and current state of weights
        loss = cost(pred, labels)  # compare of error between calculated output and real output values
    gradients = g.gradient(loss, [w])
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, [w]))
    return loss

# training loop
loss_prev = 0
for step in range(1, training_epochs + 1):
    loss_cur = run_optimization()
    if step % display_step == 0:
        print(f'__ loss: {loss_cur} d {abs(loss_cur - loss_prev)}')
    if abs(loss_cur - loss_prev) < 0.0001:
        print(f'training finished at step {step}')
        break
    loss_prev = loss_cur

pred = model(test_xs)  # calculate output using inputs and current state of weights
print(f'____ test_xs: {np.hstack((test_xs, test_labels, pred))}')
loss = cost(pred, test_labels)  # compare of error between calculated output and real output values
print(f'____ loss on test: {loss}')

plt.show()
```

Here is training data plotted by this code:

[image]

There is losses print in training loop:

```
__ loss: 175.19088925718066 d 97.1614622850586
__ loss: 464.01808014161384 d 137.1261093189229
__ loss: 295.87409849542604 d 106.07112771692539
__ loss: 198.5542021181314 d 103.10671494593691
__ loss: 313.3745043362373 d 212.29603878407113
__ loss: 110.46510727190618 d 9.733344453910249
__ loss: 281.0980936862549 d 106.50166738542168
__ loss: 132.1137415050792 d 92.80865585920446
__ loss: 410.247607390902 d 120.16339695949068
__ loss: 499.13718072403697 d 102.34586328240391
__ loss: 124.67743019826761 d 87.56485668672707
__ loss: 342.45546671469464 d 106.63645279114729
__ loss: 216.27526655142205 d 102.89180733286176
__ loss: 199.67401005744466 d 105.11010120949442
__ loss: 112.93156816716834 d 8.460631175978492
__ loss: 167.86438142934819 d 39.719945099051614
__ loss: 132.45802082539922 d 93.71055304072874
__ loss: 626.4907345545149 d 150.99914039423527
__ loss: 105.94718530421858 d 24.905386810219156
__ loss: 88.87248198748307 d 39.7884110886221
__ loss: 110.5401216713325 d 77.30643755955099
__ loss: 372.755892245448 d 264.1387840523624
__ loss: 81.01441713042172 d 80.753470922639
__ loss: 89.04901014064349 d 75.00989586702813
__ loss: 76.18304051720592 d 51.15929388583636
__ loss: 168.6565935808642 d 94.5805058639883
__ loss: 383.4937425852083 d 278.714732183915
__ loss: 277.24972063801323 d 204.0970132770799
__ loss: 400.9948114398798 d 281.8109031203536
__ loss: 811.1742785605641 d 587.140320257259
__ loss: 176.11718432939185 d 87.71991999223363
__ loss: 300.1971690346987 d 107.56085234803146
__ loss: 328.2751772445432 d 232.06366455601244
__ loss: 119.34557016163812 d 19.288352267448246
__ loss: 373.57404538292633 d 108.82435525723884
__ loss: 229.42214644748827 d 102.26426399289534
__ loss: 259.2051701408715 d 107.47098105478545
__ loss: 322.35708285227855 d 217.70388788283157
__ loss: 316.97923150268025 d 105.3901580161974
__ loss: 178.59189718843922 d 94.51360930567171
__ loss: 389.9991071853915 d 108.5725946749709
__ loss: 296.7869987520748 d 106.25613038953372
__ loss: 412.38870983207437 d 286.7650941126253
__ loss: 336.68934690839717 d 221.29986493354414
__ loss: 206.13737166173664 d 96.41918519938693
__ loss: 232.658546843127 d 144.2779069793657
__ loss: 251.75097804664264 d 166.7464171780134
__ loss: 176.43811874887848 d 103.84346478970366
__ loss: 609.4620952783437 d 107.98218081078198
__ loss: 67.42387193058754 d 70.9987193041468
__ loss: 244.73081553679955 d 105.26632075357125
__ loss: 193.89776170958137 d 105.74589021296028
__ loss: 174.65932999970806 d 97.33721508077105
__ loss: 191.1311825855965 d 98.66956897822348
__ loss: 77.01390135024863 d 71.64695846266261
__ loss: 475.9067882667389 d 138.57650128576563
__ loss: 93.9947643714204 d 46.886820460852206
__ loss: 975.308629077616 d 692.7421290288187
__ loss: 153.79839559003508 d 92.18397669958017
__ loss: 94.23014122087004 d 63.340336484637064
__ loss: 289.1533887092477 d 166.3443575824569
__ loss: 120.87173008524653 d 17.74689151701591
__ loss: 102.19181638161517 d 17.61497140199188
__ loss: 157.22824454679292 d 100.05578462575536
__ loss: 93.23526128131402 d 58.80083804787154
__ loss: 491.9905552155093 d 120.50556352753028
__ loss: 213.7380554448233 d 104.85973382292869
__ loss: 78.48328863175044 d 4.906340068197466
__ loss: 643.9586375159366 d 486.7295860557855
__ loss: 397.4950660334845 d 104.98401291947903
__ loss: 151.20062091474105 d 97.19752330746559
__ loss: 138.46706487979134 d 45.57857680703262
__ loss: 126.50275837435734 d 47.05877857865097
__ loss: 246.45757337166364 d 101.90084677743059
__ loss: 196.35140873645102 d 104.51923265855234
__ loss: 83.79629036113667 d 63.83430599345027
__ loss: 153.6345250697656 d 77.42782822087871
__ loss: 312.31603485361245 d 107.54912100186942
__ loss: 188.17570257459474 d 99.60747912197874
__ loss: 76.21634047438783 d 5.387733066733219
__ loss: 224.3671301753508 d 131.53145789410834
__ loss: 198.8484611929767 d 99.81549905051654
__ loss: 229.98720443921266 d 103.71576122087677
__ loss: 88.4928808053648 d 39.42845065849964
__ loss: 210.8263578364823 d 95.70036179973889
__ loss: 139.60009920614073 d 32.72362876620606
__ loss: 652.1955684544624 d 521.8708281346834
__ loss: 595.0853905371788 d 107.3163814462963
__ loss: 315.5663392573162 d 106.35439891700173
__ loss: 363.94959772854816 d 109.65676757589404
__ loss: 189.2799391169702 d 102.08390911209423
__ loss: 126.10631385675259 d 92.22758742234458
__ loss: 161.39518715580218 d 100.7096530257891
__ loss: 342.059340318876 d 106.2021814341079
__ loss: 390.430842116699 d 107.89685823064099
__ loss: 78.43529433403457 d 42.82619464281581
__ loss: 292.4140010813944 d 191.14537808113107
__ loss: 187.96289566741882 d 103.42363982195434
__ loss: 396.97273426606336 d 106.39762145765184
__ loss: 94.73413582836773 d 7.3598941872523795
```

And here is result of classification on test data:

[image]

First two columns here is test data. Next three columns are encoded actual label of each test point (`[1 0 0]` is label `0`, `[0 1 0]` is label `1` and `[0 0 1]` is label `2`) generated at the beginning of source code. Last three columns are calculated labels.
And it looks like training gone wrong as model able to classify labels `1` and `2` (green boundaries on the screenshot) while completely mistaken on classification label `0` (red boundaries).

Whenever I tried (increase training steps, increase amount of training dots, get widen distance between training dots) - no luck. Another thing confusing me - randomly changed loss during training process ( I expect it to me constantly reduced). So could someone please explain what I missed and how to get proper classification?

Comment: Looks like overfitting problem, increasing train steps doesn't solve problem. Take a look at other parameters like regularizer, activation function, drop some neurons avoid overfitting, Use right optimizer. Thanks!